# Why EF not updating FK column when entity state is not Added?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have such entity:

```
 public class Entity1
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }
        public int Entity2Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
    }
```

And have such one to Many relationship:

```
  this.HasRequired(m => m.Entity2)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.Entity2Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And here is the thinkg which I cannot understand:

For example, evertyhting works fine if I have changed the entity state to `Added` firstly:

```
context.Entry(entity1).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
entity1.Entity2.Id = 541;

 // Since this line `entity1.Entity2Id` value is 0.
 context.Entry(entity1.Entity2).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
 // But now everything is fine, because `entity1.Entity2Id` value is 541 also.

 context.Entry(entity1).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

But, I don't want to change state to `Added`, when I am removing the first line, this exception occured:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Beacuse, `entit1.Entity2Id != entity1.Entity2.Id`.

And, I don't want manually to change the value.

How, I can make it work without changing the state to `Added`?

***Update***:

I have investigated this problem more. From this [So question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553688/do-i-have-to-set-foreign-key-properties-manually-when-i-change-associations)

This is called **property fixup**, and used to be done automatically by the generated proxies. However, with DbContext this is no longer the case. According to this Connect issue, this is by design.

> Hello, The DbContext template actually doesn't generate classes that
>   will be used as change tracking proxies - just lazy loading proxies
>   (which don't do fix-up). We made this decision because change tracking
>   proxies are complex and have a lot of nuances that can be very
>   confusing to developers. If you want fix-up to occur before
>   SaveChanges you can call myContext.ChangeTracker.**DetectChanges**. ~EF
>   Team

An alternative is to call DbContext.Entry(entity), which will sync up the entity. This is described in this article: Relationships and Navigation Properties under "Synchronizing the changes between the FKs and Navigation properties"

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @wahwahwah I am using EF 5.0

Comment: did you take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258314/both-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-5-code-first)? depending on your EF config you might need to drop your current context and rerun it

Comment: @wahwahwah I don't understand you. First of all I didn't find any sentence about dropping context in your link. And the second one is that IMHO I will lost all entities if I will drop entity.

Comment: both entities are originally detached?

Comment: @jjj Yes, they have not any relation with context yet the first line.

Comment: Can you set `entity1.entity2Id = 541` then attach `entity1` onto the context?

Comment: @Shoe No, then it is giving the above exception in my answer, because, it will not change `entity1.Entity2.Id`.

Comment: Are entity1 & entity2 new or existing in the db?

Comment: @Shoe The procedure is. `Entity1` is coming to my method from web service for inserting or updating in  the database. But, I searched the database and found that Entity2 is already existing in the database. So, I set it's ID and also it's state to unchanged. My method works fine with reflection. The one problem is that, I don't want to set entity's state to added. To tell the truth it is not a problem also, because y method correctly changes it's state to modified or unchanged. But, I can't understand how **does EF detects changes and why it is detecting after adding not attaching?**